# Pass every column of every row of a datatable to a method using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am seeking a way of avoiding nested foreach loops for a task. I want to pass the column name and column value to a method, for every column and every row of a datatable. The method is for logging. I want the name and value to be concatenated as part of the process so the resulting string is the log message string argument. Furthermore, I'd like the structure of the datatable to be unknown. I am thinking Linq can do this. However, after writing datatable.AsEnumerable() my mind goes blank.

Comment: Why cant you pass the datatable or the rows collection?  Both have all the rows

Comment: The goal is to pass each column name and value to a logging method so I end up with the log entry of <column name> = <column value>. So part of the linq I envision is concatenating the name and value together when passing them as the log message.

Comment: See, that kind of information is important in the post (along with extant efforts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `ItemArray` of each `DataRow` to process all the column values in each row.

First collect all the column names together, so you won't have to keep doing it:

```
var colnames = dt.Columns
                 .Cast<DataColumn>()
                 .Select(dc => dc.ColumnName)
                 .ToList();
```

Then combine the column names with the row values for each row:

```
var ans = dt.AsEnumerable() // foreach DataRow in DataTable
            .Select(r => r.ItemArray // foreach item in DataRow.ItemArray
                          .Zip(colnames, // foreach colname in DataTable.Columns.ColumnName
                               (item, colname) => $"{colname} = {item}") // ColumnName = ColumnValue
                   );
```

If you want to pass the result to a logging function, just use `foreach` with `SelectMany` to flatten:

```
foreach (var msg in ans.SelectMany(r => r))
    LogData(logType, msg);
```

Comment: Say the method I want to call is LogData(int logType, string message). Can that method be added somewhere within your second linq statement? Assume you have logType as a variable in scope and message is going to equal your interpolated string.